# Как правильно использовать переменные для счетчика?

Tags: java, swing

Есть у меня счетчик который отсчитывает n-e количество времени

Я заметил когда открыл диспетчер задач, что с каждой секундой память используемая приложением увеличивается, что не есть хорошо

Как использовать переменные чтобы память безрассудно не тратилась впустую

Когда читал FAQ узнал что нельзя просто использовать строкоые переменные нужно использовать StringBuffer или StringBuilder для частого изменения

Так как у меня отображается такая информация в приложении то приведу небольшой пример кода без библиотек и остального ненужного кода

```
public static StringBuffer time_buffer = new StringBuffer();
public void timerStart()
{
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            time_buffer.setLength(0);
            time_buffer.append(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));
            jLabel.setText(time_buffer);
            ///Здесь условие выхода и остановка таймера timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
public static void main()
{
    Frame window = new Frame();
    window.setVisible(true);
    timer.start();
    window.timerStart();
}
```

Comment: *чтобы память безрассудно не тратилась впустую* - о каких объемах речь?

Comment: ну допустим каждую секунду в StringBuffer записывается новое значение в течении 2ух часов и за все это время может потратится памяти около 100 и более мб

Comment: Почему вы не хотите просто написать `jLabel.setText(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));`?

Comment: Это немного упрощенный пример, поэтому тут написано именно так
И да что от этого изменится?